# Test if text fits on one line

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, margins

I have a boxed text that is justified, but I would like to make it centered if it takes only one line. Currently, once the text is rendered, I add a `\filcenter` as an option to my box macro, but I'm wondering if I could do that automatically.

**Edit:**

My current code is :

```
% central quote
\newcommand{\dvbox}[2][]{%
  \begin{center}\doublebox{%
    \parbox{10cm}{%
      \vspace{3mm}%
        \begin{Center}%
          \makeatletter
          \@raggedtwoe@spaceskipfalse
          \@raggedtwoe@everyselectfont
          \makeatother
          \parbox{9cm}{#1\textsc{#2}}%
        \end{Center}%
      \vspace{3mm}%
    }
  }\end{center}}
```

Currently, I pass `\filcenter` as `#1` for single lines, and `#2` is the text to display.

@Martin: so your solution gives me this:

```
\makeatletter
% justify or center
\newsavebox{\@justcentbox}%
\newcommand{\justifyorcenter}[1]{%
  \sbox \@justcentbox{#1}% 
  \ifdim \wd \@justcentbox >\hsize #1%
  \else \centerline{#1} \fi
}

% central quote
\newcommand{\dvbox}[2][]{%
  \begin{center}\doublebox{%
    \parbox{10cm}{%
      \vspace{3mm}%
        \begin{Center}%
          \@raggedtwoe@spaceskipfalse
          \@raggedtwoe@everyselectfont
          \parbox{9cm}{\justifyorcenter{#1\textsc{#2}}}%
        \end{Center}%
      \vspace{3mm}%
    }
  }\end{center}}
  \makeatother
```

Comment: How is the `Center` environment defined? You need to place `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` outside the `\dvbox` definition. They must be active when the macro is defined, not when it is used.

Comment: The `Center` environment is from `ragged2e`.

Comment: You updated code looks rights. You could use the box using `\usebox{\@justcentbox}` in the else branch instead of `#1`, which is more efficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard `\caption` macro shows this behaviour. The formatting is actually done by the internal `\@makecaption` macro:

```
\@makecaption:
\long macro:#1#2->\vskip \abovecaptionskip \sbox \@tempboxa {#1: #2}\ifdim \wd \@tempboxa >\hsize #1: #2\par
\else \global \@minipagefalse \hb@xt@ \hsize {\hfil \box \@tempboxa \hfil }\fi \vskip \belowcaptionskip
```

So: Store the content in a box (e.g. using `\savebox\yourbox{<content>}`, measure the width using `\ifdim\wd\yourbox>\hsize` (or `\linewidth`) and then center it or not. In the second case you need to typeset the content a second time, while in the first you can reuse the saved box. This simplest thing to center one line is `\centerline{...}` which is very similar to the code `\@makecaption` uses.

Comment: Very interesting thanks. To clarify things, I will add my current code to the question. Should I put the test part inside the `\parbox{9cm}` part?